# replacing anchor # to full url in wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, url, anchor

I trying to replace the anchor "#downloadbutton" to the full url in all posts.
for example:
#downloadbutton =  https://mywebsite.com/kindness-and-gentleness/#downloadbutton
#downloadbutton  =  https://mywebsite.com/islamic-etiquette/#downloadbutton
#downloadbutton  =  https://mywebsite.com/hindrances-on-the-path/#downloadbutton.

The reason for this is that when I create excerpts which include anchors from the posts. The anchor urls are not working except if i go back to and change the anchor #download to absolute (full) url. and there many posts. Is there any way to do it through php snippets. Am using wordpress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**You can't remove hyperlinks hooks from the url**. Hyperlinks hooks are just a way to navigate to a specific content more quickly. For example https://ownwebsite.com/#testimonials will show you the testimonials section straight away on page load.

**The only thing you can do** is replace the url from the button with your specific url, that way instead of having an hyperlink hook button, you would have a regular plain'ol button that redirect you to a page or else..

You can learn more about the `<a>` html5 tag behaviour @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp and you can see a live example of the behaviour @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

Comment: i dont intent to remove hyperlinks from the document but to use them as full urls.suppose you have a post with url www.mywebsite.com/somepost. if i am pointing to some specific heading in the post i would just right "#some-heading". However, i want to replace this anchor with full url which is supposed to look like www.mywebsite.com/somepost/#some-heading.  I could do this manually but i have large number of posts i need to change

Comment: hyperlinks hooks are default behaviour based. Your problem is coming from your permalinks. you should take a look at your permalinks in your admin console. you can use `flush_rewrite_rules();` at the top of your `function.php` file to make sure your new rules are applied.